# Starting another application from broadcast receiver

Tags: android, android-activity, broadcastreceiver

I am trying to start an activity from a Receiver after the device boot:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.setComponent(ComponentName.unflattenFromString("other.apps.package.name/.ActivityName"));
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER); 
context.startActivity(intent);
```

This code just works fine when I call it from my activity however it fails when my BroadcastReceiver executes it after bootup. My Logcat shows:

```
ActivityNotFoundException: Have you declared the activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

Any pointers will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you get solution? same problem i am facing..

Comment: @PankajAndroid;@RagunathJawahar: Pls share solution if you got.

Answer (score 1):

> Intent intent = new Intent(context, activity.class);
>       intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
>       context.startActivity(intent);

i think this 3 lines only needed and the context will be the context u receive in broadcast receiver.

Comment: I am trying to start a different application.

Answer (score 0):

You probably spelled or made a error when you declared your Activity in your manifest. Make sure you put it in there and spelled everything correctly

Comment: I am trying to start an activity from another application and it works when I call the function from an event listener in my application's activity. It's the same method that's being called.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in the following Line.what is the name of your Activity?is it "ActivityName"?Also Check package name.

```
intent.setComponent(ComponentName.unflattenFromString("other.apps.package.name/.ActivityName"))
```

Comment: Think I mentioned - 'code just works fine when I call it from my activity'